# Access denied for user 'root'@'[PCName]' (using password; YES)

Tags: mysql, vb.net, networking

I badly need your help. I am a newbie/wannabe programmer. I am currently developing an Attendance Management System for my School which will monitor the attendance (In/Out) of the students. I have finished coding the software using VB.NET. I am testing the software which will access the database from a local PC (via LAN). But i am getting the error: 
"Authentication to host '192.168.0.1' .... Access denied for user 'root'@'[PCName]' (using password; YES)

- 192.168.0.1 - IP address of Server
- 192.168.0.2 - IP address of Client PC
- MySQL Connection: 192.168.0.1:3306
- I have tried Creating and Granting ALL PRIVILEGES TO 'root'@'%'.
- I have also tried Creating and Granting ALL PRIVILEGES to 'root'@'[PCName]'
- I have also tried Creating and Granting ALL PRIVILEGES to 'root'@'192.168.0.2'

But no luck. I am hoping you can help me.
Thank you.

Best regards,

Arvin

Comment: Try installing Workbench and see if you can connect from there.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you need to allow access as remote to your mysql here is a detailed explanation;
https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

I hope it will be helpful for you and you can solve your problem

Comment: Thank you very much Sir for your answer. The tutorial is very comprehensive however I am running a windows version of MySQL 8.0, and the tutorial is for LINUX and UNIX-like Systems. If you could enlighten me Sir on how to allow remote access on MySQL for windows. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi dear i am not really familiar with windows mysql server but most probably there is a config file as a same name as in linux find that at the install folder and edit the config adn change the bind-address to your ip address and it hopfully work.